# How to get current QString text from QComBox automatically in c++?

Tags: c++, qt

Normally I saw, When `QComboBox` is being used in Qt user interface, in order to run the program with current `QString` text from `QComboBox`, there has to be a `QPushButton`, by pressing which the program run with the current `QString` text from `QComboBox` and thus the current `QString` text can be obtained. But I want to know if there is any function in `QComboBox`, which will pass currently changed `QString` text from `QComboBox` to the program automatically. I mean, when I change `QComboBox` current text, the program will automatically run with the action of this particular current text instead of pressing the `QPushButton` again and again.

It may be a task of  very simple function, but surprisingly I am not able to find it out.

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look at how to use signals to be notified when things change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QComboBox signals like

```
void currentIndexChanged(int index)
void currentIndexChanged(const QString &text)
void currentTextChanged(const QString &text)
void editTextChanged(const QString &text)
```

Connect these signals to the proper slot, it automatically notifies slot.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html), it is possible to see the available notifier signals for this matter:

```
void    currentIndexChanged(int index)
void    currentIndexChanged(const QString & text)
```

Using them you can have your problem solved.

You can use then *connect* to handle the event:

```
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)), SLOT(yourfunction(QString)));
```

Creating your own `yourfunction()` or just using Qt Creator interface.